# PHP header() does not work

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

Does somebody know why my header() does not redirect?

The last part of my script is:

```
  header("location: test.php");
  die('died');
```

It writes:

```
died.
```

:(((

It should has to redirect before it dies, but it does not.

Do you have you any idea?

Comment: How can I do it? Just simply click a feedback yes or no?

Comment: Turn on error_reporting, error_level, etc... in PHP. You'll most likely get an "Cannot send headers - output already started at line XXX" error.

Comment: @mario that is not what downvotes are meant for. since you like linking to the faqs, here's one for you too... [Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) Oh, and I will remove my answer, which actually helped him solve his question, but violates the standards.

Comment: @mario then make a comment for the poster to expand more... we're not here to make beginners feel uncomfortable posting questions. you think everyone knows innately about the "headers-already-sent" problem? if something isn't clear just ask for more details, get them involved, don't just start the downvote train.

Comment: @mario let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2813/discussion-between-matt-k-and-mario)

Comment: Location should be absolute (not relative) although many browsers will allow, typically a header won't work because something is already output, it's often an errant space or newline at the top of a `.php` file {before `<?php`} ;)

Comment: Check this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419110/header-does-not-work-on-my-server

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's probably that you're calling header() **after** you are outputting some text/HTML to the browser, which is a no-no.  Your header() call will be ignored if even so much as a single space of output has been sent before the call.

In other words, your header() code needs to be at the start of your script, before you display **anything** to the user.  If that still isn't working, make sure you don't have any spaces or other whitespace by mistake outside of your php tags.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is some invisible output before `header`, which is preventing setting `header`, and informative warnings are suppressed.

Additionally Location-Headers should contain an absolute URL:

```
// Show Errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
// Redirect
header('Location: http://example.com/path/test.php');
die('redirect');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a fully-qualified address for your location header, and *not* output any content:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/test.php');
die();
```

Additionally make sure that no other content was sent before setting the header, otherwise it wont be sent as the headers will have already been sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

`location:` should be `Location:`.

Moreover...

- Scroll to the top of this page.
- Click on your account name.
- Click on a random question
- Check mark a random answer
- Come back to find more serieus answers

Good luck.

Comment: Dear MattK, When you coding for a long-long hours and a long-long code created, and your code before a presentation and off course the error reports are turned off, and the f.. header doesnt redirects though a f... echoed empty string... What do you do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this error, too, and tried to show errors with error_reporting(E_ALL),
but this didn't worked for me. Info: I was using a hosting service on Strato.

The solution to all this was answered by Floem, thanks for this great setup.

If you ever don't get errors in case you put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` once in,
-> **You must additionally add** `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')`, to force PHP to show all your Errors. This solved my Error issue on

Then it's possible to read out, why PHP wouldn't make your redirect.
One tip on my side: I would recommend you to build a little redirect Class, as shown in this Video: [Redirect Class for easy use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEzJHww-QwM&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc&index=16), if you're going to use this redirect more than usual.

Answer (score 0):

Just resolve it by removing ALL things before the php tag.

**Remove the SPACE before the php tag**

Select all before the tag and then push the erase button.

Answer (score 0):

If the file containing the 'header()' instruction is required directly/indirectly in a HTML file, then the instruction {include 'someFile'} should be the first line of that HTML file. Place this instruction on the top of your HTML file, as shown in [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjHjn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add

`ob_start();`

before

```
header("location: test.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original question the die() function is executed while there is a header() just before.
I had a similar problem so I created the code below to test.

```
header("Location:index.php");

$file = fopen("test.txt","a");
fwrite($file,date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n");
fclose($file);
```

And...? Well the code present after the `header()` function is executed and after only the header() returns to the `index.php` page.
All that to say that the `header()` function can be used at the end of a script to refer to another script.
But **BE CAREFUL** if this is positioned at the start of the script, it **does not prevent** the script from running.