# Header does not work on my server

Tags: php, function, header

Please I have a small problem on my server :

When I use the php "header" function, it doesn't work :

```
header('location: /index.html');
```

I tried this line on another server with the same php version and it works finely  !

PHP version : 5.1.65

Please any advice ?

Comment: Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file. - from http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thanks Dylan. But it works very well on the first server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dylan Cross mentioned you mustn't have HTML output before the header.

If you have required a library before calling "header", it might contain the html -without paying attention- in the fallowing way :

```
<?php 

   // Code here

?>{If there is a space after this close tag, it's considered as an HTML output}
```

In this case you need to check all your libraries...

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Location: /index.html');
                ^---missing colon
```

Comment: then check if there's any output before this, causing a "headers already sent" warning. display_errors/error_reporting MUSt be turned on when you're debugging a problem. don't work with both hands tied behind your back.

Comment: Thanks I understand, there is no warning and no html that is already sent ! In fact I must redirect to home after logging out. it works on one server but not on the other one !

Comment: doesn't have to be html. just anything that triggers php to flush headers and start output BEFORE that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you missed out the colon(`:`):

```
header('location: /index.html');
```